# cannot read more than one data group (matrix, array) in the file

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

If you could help me, that would be much appreciated.  Problem is that I have to read more than one group of data in file. That is, it will read different variables. For example, I have a data file, it will read for the distance matrix (x1,x2,y1,y2) first, it will read the cost matrix when it is finished. Then it will read demand array. I mean, I have to read something new on the new line. How can I do? Help me please.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>

 int main()
 {
     FILE* myfile;
     errno_t errorcode = fopen_s(&myfile, "output.txt", "w");

     if (myfile == NULL)
     {
        printf("Error");
     }

     FILE* data; 
     errno_t err = fopen_s(&data, "C:\\SA\\input.txt", "r");

     if(data==NULL)
     {
        printf("file does not open");
     }
     int s;
     while (fscanf_s(data, "%d", &s) == 1)
     {
        printf("s:%d", s);
     }
     float dist[5][15], y1, y2, x1, x2;
     int cost[5][15];
     int demand[15];
     dist[5][15] = sqrt(pow((y2-y1),2)+pow((x2-x1),2));

 return 0;

 }
```

Input file (example)

```
 2 4 50 4
 1 37 52 0   7 1 4 1 2 4 8
 2 49 49 0  30 1 4 1 2 4 8
 3 52 64 0  16 1 4 1 2 4 8
 4 20 26 0   9 1 4 1 2 4 8
 5 40 30 0  21 1 4 1 2 4 8
```

Comment: What is your input file? Can you post a sample file here?

Comment: If I understand correctly then your distance matrix is `5x15` while your input data contains data of size `5x11`.

Comment: And `dist[5][15] = sqrt(pow((y2-y1),2)+pow((x2-x1),2));` this has another story for sure, will discuss later.

Comment: Ece Uyar, `dist[5][15] = ...` is bad.  What are you trying to do here?